# Models appear black in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

Ive been trying to draw a simple cube in xna but its showing up completely black. Ive tried multiple diffirent FBX models. Played around with the settings for the models in the pipeline. Ive also to apply basic lightning in every way possible. Its still appearing black.

My code:

```
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
 using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
 using System;

namespace Game1
{

public class Game1 : Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    BasicEffect effect;
    Texture2D floor;
    Model model;

    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
    }

    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        effect = new BasicEffect(graphics.GraphicsDevice);

        base.Initialize();
    }

    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        spriteBatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        floor = Content.Load<Texture2D>("floor");
        model = Content.Load<Model>("cube");
    }

    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed || Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Escape))
            Exit();


        base.Update(gameTime);
    }

    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);
        var cameraPosition = new Vector3((float)Math.Cos((double)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds/1000)*20, 40, (float)Math.Cos((double)gameTime.TotalGameTime.TotalMilliseconds / 1000) * 20);
        var cameraLookAtVector = Vector3.Zero;
        var cameraUpVector = Vector3.UnitZ;

        effect.View = Matrix.CreateLookAt(
            cameraPosition, cameraLookAtVector, cameraUpVector);

        float aspectRatio =
            graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth / (float)graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight;
        float fieldOfView = Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MathHelper.PiOver4;
        float nearClipPlane = 1;
        float farClipPlane = 200;

        effect.Projection = Matrix.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(
            fieldOfView, aspectRatio, nearClipPlane, farClipPlane);

        effect.TextureEnabled = true;
        effect.Texture = floor;

        drawModel(model, effect.World, effect.View, effect.Projection);

        foreach (var pass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
        {
            pass.Apply();

            drawQuad(new Vector3[] {
                new Vector3(20,-20,0),
                new Vector3(-20,-20,0),
                new Vector3(-20,20,0),
                new Vector3(20,20,0),
            },2f);
        }


        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }

    public void drawQuad(Vector3[] p, float tiling)
    {
        VertexPositionNormalTexture[] verts = new VertexPositionNormalTexture[6];

        verts[0].Position = p[0];
        verts[1].Position = p[1];
        verts[2].Position = p[3];

        verts[3].Position = p[1];
        verts[4].Position = p[2];
        verts[5].Position = p[3];

        verts[0].Normal = p[0];
        verts[1].Normal = p[1];
        verts[2].Normal = p[3];

        verts[3].Normal = p[1];
        verts[4].Normal = p[2];
        verts[5].Normal = p[3];

        verts[0].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, 0);
        verts[1].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(0, tiling);
        verts[2].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(tiling, 0);

        verts[3].TextureCoordinate = verts[1].TextureCoordinate;
        verts[4].TextureCoordinate = new Vector2(tiling, tiling);
        verts[5].TextureCoordinate = verts[2].TextureCoordinate;

        graphics.GraphicsDevice.DrawUserPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, verts, 0, 2);
    }

    public void drawModel(Model model, Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection)
    {
        foreach (var mesh in model.Meshes)
        {
            foreach (BasicEffect effect in mesh.Effects)
            {
                    effect.EnableDefaultLighting();
                    effect.DiffuseColor = Color.White.ToVector3(); 
                    effect.World = world;
                    effect.View = view;
                    effect.Projection = projection;
            }

            mesh.Draw();
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FBX doesn't embed textures in the model file itself, it just stores a path *to* the texture file. This path is usually relative to the export location (but it depends on the tool).

Try placing the texture file in the same relative path as it was with the export location, but in the output directory of the executable. Otherwise, FBX files are human readable IIRC, so you should be able to determine where it is looking for the texture, and put it there.

Comment: Ok, i did'nt use a texture file at all before. Is that a must? Anyway. I created the same cube and applied a texture to it. The texture is definitly in the correct path. When i build the content in the pipeline it returns an error if its not in the correct path. So the content build was successfull but its still completly black. This is really weird. Also, monogame does not seem to support acii fbx files, they need to be binary.

Comment: @ceoepts yes, XNA supports very few "materials". You need to include the texture files. Did the texture also compile into an XNB? Did you include it?

Comment: Yes, ive included everything in the monogame pipeline. I can see all the xnb's inside the bin folder. I dont really know what more to test :/

Comment: @ceoepts You may also try not manually setting the texture on the `Effect` object, but its really hard to say what is wrong :(

Comment: Ahh, i just figured it out. Blender doesn't seem to export a working xna file. It sais that it does on the addon registry. I had to download a fbx converter from autodesk and convert it. I also noticed that i could use dae files instead. Do you know if there is any cons to using them? Anyway, after i converted the fbx file it works great. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ceoepts I typically use Autodesk products :) Softimage Mod tool (if you can get it) works really well. I don't know of any pros or cons to DAE, but I haven't used it.

Comment: I'll try 3ds max or maya seeing as those are included in my education pack, anyway, thanks for the help :)

Comment: FBX [supports](http://download.autodesk.com/us/fbx/20112/FBX_SDK_HELP/index.html?url=WS1a9193826455f5ff7b1de9f8127315f1b54-5a50.htm,topicNumber=d0e1054) embedded textures, but of course the exporter and importer must support it.

Comment: @KobyDuck Must be that XNA doesn't support imports then; because I have had 0 luck with it in the past :)